# How to avoid transparent creation of scope objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am learning to use AngularJS and have stumbled upon something, which I view as bad design.

I am following the [docs about forms](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) and am re-creating the given examples. My code can be viewed here - http://paste.ubuntu.com/6443123/.

What concerns me is that I haven't declared the `user` object anywhere in the JavaScript code. However, its use within the form transparently adds it to the scope (I can `console.log` it within the `save` method), where it stays indefinitely. I feel that this could lead to subtle bugs, where you would expect the user object to be undefined (since it hasn't been used in the controller), but instead, it already contains data.

Is this expected by design? Isn't there a cleaner way to separate such "temporary" models from your scope?

Comment: This is by design, and I don't see it as bad design.  It comes if very handy, specially in the case of form validation.  Once you get used to it, I think you may change your view.

Comment: saves  lot of time letting angular create the binding without having to go through every form control and create your own scope variables/objects. Then when ready to submit/save, all form data is instantly available in scope

Comment: Implicit variable declaration is a "feature" of javascript.  It does take a bit of getting used to for those of us who come from staticly typed languages.  Here's an article that, while focused on typing, I think is relevant here as I find a lot of discussion between implicit and explicit to be similar to the static vs dynamic debate:  http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/18/introduction-to-programming-type-systems/

Comment: Guys, just because something is 'handy', 'easier', and so on, doesn't mean that it's good design. This violates the Law of Demeter by giving extra information to the scope transparently.